# Visual studio can't work with two origin urls

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to keep in sync two repository hosted in two different sites (Github and Bitbucket) following a guide i added a new origin url to the config and now my .git/config looks like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://rrev@bitbucket.org/rrev/sampclient.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
url = https://github.com/rrev/SAMPClient.git
```

Now Github and Bitbucket have the same commits and the same source code but when i try to push a commit to the two repositories Visual Studio sends the commit only to Github leaving the Bitbucket behind.

It looks like Visual Studio doesn't work well with two urls because, when i moved `url = https://github.com/rrev/SAMPClient.git` in `[remote "all"]` for testing, Visual Studio sends correctly the commit to Bitbucket and when i put back the Github url it detected that the repository was behind the local repository.

It's a limitation of Visual Studio? Because when i use the command line to push the changes (using `git push`) the two repositories gets synced correctly.

Comment: Please file a connect bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/ - that will help us track this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of Visual Studio. How you can see if using `git push` all working good.

-Anton Ego

Comment: I will guess that Visual Studio is not using the command line but something like [libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/).  This is a good thing, but libgit2 has no simple equivalent to `git push`.  You have to code a lot it yourself and subtle differences can leak in.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you need two remotes, you need two remotes.</strike>  *I'm totally wrong, `git push` will honor multiple URLs.*  <strike>I can't tell if this is a deliberate or accidental feature.</strike> *[According to libgit2 this is a deliberate feature of Git for exactly your situation](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/2891#issuecomment-73377528)*.

My guess is that Visual Studio is not using the git command line but is instead using a library such as [libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/) (*confirmed*).  libgit2 is a much faster and more reliable option (especially on Windows) for an application to use Git than by wrapping the command line.  libgit2 does not have direct analogies to the Git command line, working with remotes is particularly involved.  libgit2 remotes can only have one url, [it's baked into their data structure and API](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/remote).

My suggestion is to either push from the command line, or two have two remotes and remember to push to both of them, or decide one of them is a mirror and set up an automatic process to sync it, or (IMO best) decide you don't need to maintain an identical repository on a redundant development service.

Comment: Actually, I'm totally wrong.  You CAN have two urls for the same remote.  Bizarre.  I guess @AntonEgo is right.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno You would have to issue a separate push for each remote.

Comment: Maybe using two remotes and then `git push <remote_name>` could resolve the problem. Now I have moved the repository to Github, so it's not a problem anymore for me, but it could help someone who have the same problem.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno [The word from the libgit2 folks](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/2891#issuecomment-73377528), which Visual Studio does use, is this is a feature of Git for exactly your situation. They consider it low priority and don't know how to handle it.

Comment: Something that might do is have a local proxy repo that runs real git, a post-receive hook to forward inbound pushes to a two-url upstream should be very easy.  I suspect you'd have to run a local [git-daemon](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html) (listening only on localhost) to actually invoke git for it.